# Add store to already open IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

Is there a way to create a `store` in an `IndexedDB` after it has been `open` and passed the `onupgradeneeded`?

I tried:

```
var store = db.createObjectStore('blah', {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement:true});
```

Get this error:

```
InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an object store that already exists? Use `db.objectStoreNames.contains('object-store-name')` to check.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. For example, the sentence "passed the onupgradeneeded" is not proper English and does not make technical sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Josh, you need to clarify your question.

I suggest you try a different approach. Delete the database and create a new one.

```
var request = window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase('somedb');
request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log('Error', event);
}
request.onsuccess = function(event){
    console.log('Success', event);
    //recreate database
    createNewDB();
}
```

**NOTE**

You will need to `close()` the connection before you are able to remove the `database` and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`var store = db.createObjectStore(...)`

I mean you should remove the word 'obj'

You can take a look at the example [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/)

Comment: not sure what you want me to do here? you asking me to try and remove a store that is not there?

Comment: oh, no that is not the issue, it is just the way my method is setup, I should just remove the db.obj and put db for the question, My guess is you can not add tables to the database once it has completed the onupgradeneeded method.